# How do you map to localhost:port in NGINX config map directive?

Tags: nginx, config

```
...

    map $http_origin $corsHost  {
        default '-miss-me-wit-dis-yo-';

        hostnames;
        .namethatmaps.net $http_origin;
        http://localhost:5555 # working sample
        localhost $http_origin; # sample 1
        .localhost:555.+ $http_origin; # sample 2
    }
```

Always fails this test value `$http_origin = http://localhost:5555`

Is there no pattern to wildcard localhost?

Answer (score 0):

This solved for my use case:

```
map $http_origin  $corsHost  {
    ...
    hostnames;
    ~localhost:555 $http_origin;
}
```